# How to obtain data from a site that uses javascript?

Tags: bash, html, http, javascript

What I want is to query metallum to obtain a plain list of songs that contain x word, let's say spider, so the query for the browser would be https://www.metal-archives.com/search?searchString=spider&type=song_title I suspect that the site uses javascript so how do I do the same thing using bash?

Answer (score 0):

Just try the following command :

```
curl 'https://www.metal-archives.com/search/ajax-song-search/?field=title&query=spider'
```

(You may also use `wget`)

**Explanations :**

In your case, I get your page with `curl` and the URL you have proposed, and see :

```
<script type="be2873e53ee178327a06d401-text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
                        createGrid(
                        "#searchResults", 200, 
                        "search/ajax-song-search/?field=title&query=spider",
```

I had just to assemble your `https://www.metal-archives.com/` prefix with the last quoted string.

In other cases, the JavaScript can be harder to analyse and it could be easier to use a debugging proxy like OWASP ZAP (not tested).

Comment: thank you very much! You-ll have to explain me later how did you do it. And how to do that in general

Comment: Some explanations added.

Comment: damn I only saw this page: https://www.metal-archives.com/js/jquery/jquery.dataTables.min.js
I thought that was the function but wasn-t working.

Comment: there-s still a problem:
The resulting json contains only the first 100's of the results, how can I get them all? Also is there any method to retrieve a lyrics poertaining to bands from only a single country?